# Raise property changed for indexer not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code an Indexer and an event from our framework, that raise the property change event for the XAML binding.

I binded some XAML control on the indexer, the binding works cause it breaks in the get when I initialize the interface. But, when I change the value of the control, it breaks in the `OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged` method, and enter the `if` condition and call the `OnPropertyChanged` event with the Indexer name. But the interface never refresh.

One weird thing, is that at first, when I wrote this code, it was working the UI was refreshing, then after I renamed `Total` to `DailyTotal` and since then it stopped working. Does anyone has a clue of why the Indexer is not refreshed.

Here's an exemple of my XAML control with binding :

```
<max:MaxLabel x:Name="tbnTotalHour1" max:CustomBindingBehavior.IsCustomBindingIgnored="True" Content="{Binding Path=[0], Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The code :

```
protected override void OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (sender is TimeSheet)
         this.OnPropertyChanged("Total[]")
}

[IndexerName("Total")]
public long this[int dateModifier]
{
    get
    {
         var date = this.WorkingEntity.PayrollPeriodStartDate.AddDays(dateModifier);
         TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;
         foreach (var view in this.CurrentWorkingTimesheetByActivity.ViewList)
         {
              var detail = view.Details[date];
              if (detail != null)
                  total += detail.TimeSheet.Duration;
         }
         return total.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how people downvote without giving any comments.I think my question is pretty legit.

Comment: Upvoted for useful and clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding system is looking for a property named "Item[]", defined by the constant string Binding.IndexerName. In your own setter, the notify would look something like this:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
   PropertyChanged(this, new   PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
}
```

Just Update your code:

```
protected override void OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(object     sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (sender is TimeSheet)
         this.OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName)
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use your custom Indexer name, I founded this way by my self after many guessing:

Decorate your Property with the [IndexerName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) Attribute.

Change the XAML Binding with your indexer name:

```
<max:MaxLabel x:Name="tbnTotalHour1" max:CustomBindingBehavior.IsCustomBindingIgnored="True" Content="{Binding Path=Total[0], Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And in the Raising of the Changes just use the indexer name without '[]'

```
protected override void OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSomeBusinessCurrentEntityPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (sender is TimeSheet)
         this.OnPropertyChanged("Total")
}
```

Comment: It works after I removed the IndexerName above my indexer. Care to explain me why `Item[]` worked but not `Total[]` ?

Comment: I prefer to use `Binding.IndexerName`

Comment: Yeah, but why `Item[]` is working (since `Binding.IndexerName` is just a constant). but `Total[]` with the attribut that say my IndexerName is `Total` was not? i'm curious to know.

Comment: @PLAudet I Edited my post, i did my best to understand and explain the problem. i up voted your question and marked it as Favourite one.

Comment: Tks a lot for the clarification !